# What if a Weeping Angel is observed from a different point in time?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

What if the video of a Weeping Angel is observed let's say from the future or the past. Does the Angel still get frozen because it's being observed however the time setting is different?

For example: An Angel attacks your friend. He recorded it and you wanna see what happened. So the Angel is being observed through the tape. A quantum mechanic lock works only when it's not being observed by a living creature. So does the Angel still "kill" your friend? I can't find an answer so I would really appreciate it if you guys could explain what would happen.

Comment: The problem is I don't believe we've ever seen it, so we won't know until we do.  And judging by how poorly they handled the WA since their first appearance, it'll probably contradict earlier stuff and make no sense.  But the simplest fix would be that they simply automaticaly futz-out cameras when footage isn't being watched 'live' (and sometimes even when it is, allowing them to move between bursts of static.

Comment: Or they disappear being on film when not being observed by a living creature at that current moment. I guess that'd make the most sense.

Comment: I would think not.  Remember that "whatever contains an image of an angel is itself and Angel" so the recording would be a "new" Angel and not have an effect on the original Angel

Comment: Since the image of an angel is an angel, that would suck for you.  And for your friend.

Comment: Please note that literally *everything* is *always* observed in the future. To put it differently, everything you or anyone else sees is an image from the past. Distance / speed-of-light to be precise.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take this bit by bit:

#### What if the video of a Weeping Angel is observed let's say from the future or the past?

This is confusing, because normal videos are always of the past. Are you talking about looking through a time portal to observe a video of an angel?

#### Does the Angel still get frozen because it's being observed however the time setting is different?

Ye-es but as we learned in the episode with the video of the angel, nothing is to stop the angel from, for example, moving between the frames of the recording. And since even the image of an angel is an angel (such as reflecting off of your eyeballs apparently) you're still screwed.

Besides which, time begins to get wonky down on the quantum level.

For example: An Angel attacks your friend. He recorded it and you wanna see what happened. So the Angel is being observed through the tape. A quantum mechanic lock works only when it's not being observed by a living creature.

So the setup from the episode where an angel is being observed through a recording, okay.

#### So does the Angel still "kill" your friend?

Sorry, are we going with the assumption that your friend escaped and handed you the recording, or that you came afterward and found a cell phone laying on the ground? Because this seems to clearly answer the question. You observing the recording does not affect whether or not your friend was attacked.

I think you are confusing looking at a video of the past with directly affecting the past.

As I understand it, a video of an angel is its own entity. To the best of my knowledge, observing a video of an angel does not affect the angel who was being recorded however long ago it was.

#### Now, is the angel on the tape a separate entity?

That's not entirely clear. It does seem clear, however, that watching the tape of an angel causes the tape of the angel to transfer into the person doing the viewing. Is this affected if, say, two people watch the video? That is, does only one person get "infected" by the angel or do both? We just don't know.

In fact, that more or less summarizes this question- we haven't seen it, so we don't know. But there is also no reason to think that observing a video of an angel will affect it at the time either, so I would lean towards no until we have any sort of proof otherwise.